# Why isn't my div using automatic width?

Tags: css, html, width

http://www.e-fluential.com/offline/

Screen grab:
[image]

I can't get the div that the blue words blah blah is in to be automatic width, its just going full width from the margin i've set..

```
.titlesmedium {
    font-family: title_font;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-left: 340px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    color:#00C3FA;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #00C3FA;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Than you have to have on it:

```
display:block;
float:left;
```

be careful to clear the paragraph text.

Or:

```
display:inline;
margin-left:0;
```

Comment: I have managed to do it now but im not sure i've done it right but its got the effect i needed

Answer (score 0):

Automatic width for a div will be 100% minus any margins or padding you set.
If you want it to be an explicit width you will have to set that value.

Comment: I need it to be automatic width, that grows with whatever text it contains

Answer (score 0):

maybe `width:auto` will change that?

Also try `display:inline`;

Comment: tried those 2 and they don't effect it, although the display:inline moves everything up a bit on the page

Comment: `width: auto;` is the default so unless you’ve overridden the value you shouldn’t have to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

First I think most answers are correct from what I can Read. (display: inline) But i think you should reconsider how you do this. You have margin left: 340px on your header. I guess u have the same on your paragraph to? It works.

But I think you should divide everything in to i.e. articles  (or DIV) and just have a left and right column in this Article area. Then you don´t need to set all these specific margins etc on each element.

Also you should reconsider have paragraphs and headings instead of DIV in your HTML.
Also, there is no need for "titlesmedium" if you have .

article.anygoodname h1{ ...

article.anygoodname p{ ....

etc

Good luck!